# How show list certain row in view?

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-list

The list in the view is limited to showing columns. I want to include the column that I want in the columns shown in the view.

How should I do?

```
@State var showMyRow = false

var body: some view { 
   Vstack {
     Button(“bt”) {
          self.showMyRow.toggle()
      }
    ImageView
     ....
   List {
            ForEach
            .
            .
            . // if showMyRow is true, view show this row
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Above image, showMyRow is false.

[image]

After button action, showMyRow is true. 
If showMyRow is true, show me at the 7row

Answer (score 0):

Updated Answer:
Not sure if I understood your question perfectly, but if you just want a list that you can add and delete things from, then the easiest would be to create a separate SwiftUI file holding a struct for the row and an ObservableObject class that checks for any changes.

**1) SwiftUI File with ListItem struct & ObservableObject class:**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ListItem: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let title: String
}

class Items: ObservableObject {
    @Published var rows = [ListItem]()
}
```

**2) ContentView with your image view and list:**
This also has a removeItems method so you can swipe any row to delete it.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var items = Items()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                Image("image")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                    .padding(50)
                List {
                    ForEach(items.rows) { item in
                        Text(item.title)
                    }
                .onDelete(perform: removeItems)
                }
            }
        .navigationBarTitle("My List")
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action : {
                let row = ListItem(title: "New Row")
                self.items.rows.append(row)
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "plus")
            }
            )
        }
    }

    func removeItems(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        items.rows.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: So sorry, my question is lack. So the question is modified.

Comment: No worries. See updated answer. Hope that answers your question.

Comment: hmm thx for answer, but i wanna see invisible row to drag automatically in visible view. For example i do button action that show property is true, and then see that row (no drag see 1001th row). So sorry my english skill... is fool..

Comment: Does it need to be bound to a show property? See my updated answer now. You simply need to tap on the "plus" button at the top right and it will automatically add a new row.

Comment: so sorry, i remodified my question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you're trying to present multiple columns horizontally on the screen?

If so, then you can put the Lists inside a Stack

```
HStack {
    List {
        Text("Hello")
    }
    List {
        Text("There")
    }
}
```

And if there's a lot of columns, then you can wrap the HStack inside a scroll view.

```
var body: some View {
    ScrollView(.horizontal) {
        HStack {
            List {
                Text("column 1")
            }
            List {
                Text("column 2")
            }
            List {
                Text("column 3")
            }
            List {
                Text("column 4")
            }
        }    
            .frame(width: 1000, height: 800)
            .background(Color.red)
    }
}
```